# How to ground a server rack on 3rd floor office

Tags: electrical-power, rack

I am in the process of building out a server rack in an office on the 3rd floor. Does anybody know of any good options out there that can help me out? Wall outlets have 3-prong connectors with working ground (assumed).  There is probably a building ground in the IDF room.

1. Is there some sort of adapter I can plug into a wall outlet that I can attach a grounding cable to?
2. Does standard procedure require a building ground installed from the office suite all the way down to the IDF?

Comment: The first thing that I'd be doing in your situation is having a chat with the electrical contractor who did most or all of the electrical work in your building.  There is a pretty good chance that there is a suitable grounding conductor available on your floor.

Comment: Some server rack got a ground cable, and some big ups. The grounding cable that came out the wall was installed by the electrician, so as Dwayne told, better simply call your electrician for that need